# Mockito Memory leak on Libgdx Headless Application

Tags: libgdx, mockito, headless

I've been developping a multiplayer game using libgdx for the client and the server. In order to make the server run headlessly, I had to use mockito to mock the OpenGL context as it can been seen here:

```
Gdx.gl = Mockito.mock(GL20.class, Mockito.withSettings().stubOnly());
new HeadlessApplication(new MainServer(true), config);
```

However I noticed that after 5~6 hours the server crashes with this message:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "HeadlessApplication"Exception in thread "Server"
```

Since it appeared to be a memory leak, I immediatly fired the eclipse MAT(Memory Analyser Tool) and the result it pretty straightfoward: [MAT Repport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqKAo.png)
I google about "Mockito memory leak" and I found out that I could try to use the `Mockito.withSettings().stubOnly()` option as I did above but I still got the issue. in fact the screenshot from the link as been done with this option setted up.
I wanted to know if someone can explain me this issue and if there is any way to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to avoid the use of Mockito. Since I only needed to mock Gdx.gl and it wasn't for testing purpose, I simply created a dummy class called *FakeGL20* which implement the *GL20* interface without doing anything.
Then I just assign this new class to Gdx.gl: `Gdx.gl = new FakeGl20()`
After that change being made I did not have any memory leak issue.
Hope this helps someone one day.